# Could not find firebase

Tags: codenameone

After android build I get an error which say:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':releaseCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/tmp/build1451927942979979633xxx/MyApplication/libs/firebase-core.jar
  Required by:
      project :
```

google-services.json is in native/android folder

Answer (score 1):

This was a regression in our servers yesterday. It was caused by a failed update that tried to fix google maps support. Google made some changes to their maps API so we needed to update some behaviors in the build servers and inadvertently caused a regression.

Within a couple of hours this was reverted then later that night a proper fix was re-applied.